# Remote Desktop over VPN to access other VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote-server

**My current situation is:**

Site 2 can connect to site 1 via VPN. I'm on site 3. IT at site 1 doesn't allow creating a new VPN to site 1.

I'm thinking of using a Remote Desktop via VPN from site 3 to site 2, and the remote PC (in site 2) will connect to site 1.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this possible?
2. What kind of configuration do I need to setup in site 1 and site 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - although you may find that the connection is slower than a direct connection.

As for the configuration - it really depends on what systems you're running.  Windows? Linux? OSX?

Essentially, configure Site 2 to allow VPN connections from Site 3 (and *only* Site 3).

It may be worth checking with IT as to **why** they don't allow VPN connections from anywhere else.  You don't want to get in trouble :-)